# Creation of sublist using filter is not working

Tags: android, list, kotlin, mutable

I am trying to extract from a list all element which are not in the sublist already created. I cannot make it work using `.filterNot` because it filtering on the overall data class store in the list.

```
var subList2 = allList.filterNot { subList1.contains(it) }.toMutableList()
```

but allList and subList are a list of data class defined as :

```
data class Food(
    var name: Name,
    var state: State
)
```

As of now, using this code, the `sublist2` can contain food that are in `sublist1` because `state` is different.

I want the filter to be done only on `name` so the sublist2 only contain food which is not in the `sublist1` whatever the `state` is.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to map the `subList1` names:

```
val subList1Names = subList1.map { it.name }
var subList2 = allList.filterNot { it.name in subList1Names }.toMutableList()
```